# Screen capture application for RHEL6.5

Tags: linux, rhel, gnome, screenshot

I need some screen capture application for RHEL6.5 and tried few ways to get one but failed.

1. `yum install gnmoe-utils` and got:

   Reading Local RPMDB
    rpmdb time: 0.000
    Setting up Install Process
    Checking for virtual provide or file-provide for gnome-utils
    No package gnome-utils available.
    Error: Nothing to do

Q: Is there a repo or some other way to get it installed?

2. `yum install shutter`

   ```
   Error: Package: shutter-0.93-1.el6.nux.noarch (nux-dextop)
      Requires: perl(JSON)
   Error: Package: perl-Net-OAuth-0.28-1.el6.noarch (epel)
      Requires: perl(Digest::SHA)
   Error: Package: shutter-0.93-1.el6.nux.noarch (nux-dextop)
      Requires: perl(Time::HiRes)
   Error: Package: perl-Net-DBus-0.33.6-8.el6.x86_64 (epel)
      Requires: perl(Time::HiRes)
   Error: Package: perl-HTTP-Server-Simple-0.43-1.el6.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
      Requires: perl(CGI)
   Error: Package: perl-Gtk2-1.248-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
      Requires: perl(HTML::TreeBuilder)
   ..... more errors related to `perl`
   ```

Trying to get `perl`:

```
  COMMAND: yum install perl 
  Installroot: /
  Ext Commands:

     perl
  Setting up Package Sacks
  Running "exclude" handler for "security" plugin
  pkgsack time: 0.060
  Reading Local RPMDB
  rpmdb time: 0.000
  Setting up Install Process
  Checking for virtual provide or file-provide for perl
  Nothing to do
```

Q: How it can be resolved?

3. `Print Screen` shortcut is not complaining for `gnome-screenshot` not found.

Q: How it can be installed?

Ultimately, I just need some application to get screenshots.

Comment: `yum install gnome-screenshot` may well install it for you :-)

Comment: Tried that too and got this:    `rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Install Process
Checking for virtual provide or file-provide for gnome-screenshot
No package gnome-screenshot available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: Have you tried: `yum install gnome*`?

Comment: @ryekayo: Nope but I do now! It was moving but it stopped with this error:   `Error: failure: repodata/6e8ae16744b797090259a097b33c485e584aa52824f45968924cb7e9db9ca032-filelists.sqlite.bz2 from nux-dextop: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
`

Comment: Hmmm I would try using the error messages advise to see if it can fully install. If not, check the website that has the software your looking for and see if you can use wget to get the package

Comment: See [this forum post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15267)

Comment: I'd go as far as saying that you've a package manager problem more than anything else.  All your commands seem to complain about `no package ?? available`.

Comment: @flamenco - I would tend to agree with garethTheRed's assessment. Can you do a re-install on this box? It's YUM repos seem "damaged".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If none of the other options are working you can use the command line to acquire screenshots too.

```
$ import screenshot.png

$ import -window root -resize 400×300 -delay 200 screenshot.png
```

This is part of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php). There's also `scrot` too.

```
$ scrot MyScreenshot.png

$ scrot -b -d 5 '%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Desktop/'
```

In this example,

- `-b` specifies including the window borders
- `-d` specifies a delay of five seconds
- `'%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S.png'` will save the screenshot with a name based on the current date and time and with the format specified, .png in this case
- `-e 'mv $f ~/Desktop/'` tells scrot to save the screenshot to the Desktop

The above was heavily borrowed from this AU Q&A titled: [What is the terminal command to take a screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194427/what-is-the-terminal-command-to-take-a-screenshot).

Comment: `$ import screenshot.png`    
-bash: import: command not found

Comment: @flamenco - you'll have to install ImageMagick. `sudo yum install ImageMagick`.

Comment: `Checking for virtual provide or file-provide for ImageMagick
No package ImageMagick available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: @flamenco - do this, `repoquery -qf /usr/bin/import`.

Comment: I think so too. I'm new to Linux and do not know to much about `rmp` and `yum`. I got he idea how they work but as far where to look for repos and fine details, I do know to much.

Comment: If you need `scrot` on CentOS 7.x - https://wiki.psychotic.ninja/index.php?title=Main_Page it's in this repo.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try `avconv`:

`$ avconv -t 1 -s 2024x768 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -r 0.5  -f image2 foo.png`

May be a bit exaggerated, though.
Note to adjust your desktop size as "2024x768" might not fit.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it sounds as if you added a 3rd Party repo before registering with RHN.  By doing so, every package on the system is treating the third party repo as all repos.  Please:

1. Remove the 3rd-Party Repo from `/etc/yum.conf` or `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo`
2. Read all of [Chapter 5: Registering a Redhat System](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/entitlements.html)
3. Register the system as per Chapter 5.
4. Re-add the 3rd party repo.

If those steps don't work, format and redo the install if possible.  Once the install finishes, follow the instructions in Chapter 5 to Register the system.  If you were under the impression you could use RHEL without registering, and paying, you are mistaken.